# PGFPlots: Logarithmic scale with "linear" labels

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I created a bar chart with a logarithmic x axis. The problem is: The labels for the bars are also logarithmic, e.g. *1.3* instead of *20*.

How can I get the real numbers as label?

Thanks in advance.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
            xbar,
            xbar=0pt,
            enlargelimits=0.15,
            width=.9\textwidth,
            label style={font=\footnotesize},
            ytick={0,...,9},
            yticklabels = {val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9, val10},
            ytick=data,
            enlarge y limits={abs=1.125},
            nodes near coords,
            every axis plot/.append style={fill},
            y = 1.2cm,
            xmode=log,log basis x=10
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(168000, 0) (832, 1) (2696, 2) (131162, 3) (31492, 4) (6, 5) (2858, 6) (152196, 7) (698264, 8) (1100, 9)};
        \addplot coordinates {(2487066, 0) (34174, 1) (44184, 2) (409040, 3) (68204, 4) (35200, 5) (35528, 6) (656328, 7) (702332, 8) (38348, 9)};
        \addplot coordinates {(188540, 0) (1268, 1) (1848, 2) (159124, 3) (32788, 4) (836, 5) (2888, 6) (146236, 7) (499024, 8) (2696, 9)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: logarithmic bar chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding `point meta=rawx` to the `axis` options.

Because this seems to "confuse" the default `nodes near coords align=auto` you need to set the value to `horizontal` as well.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar=0pt,
        enlargelimits=0.15,
        width=.9\textwidth,
        label style={font=\footnotesize},
        ytick={0,...,9},
        yticklabels = {val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9, val10},
        ytick=data,
        enlarge y limits={abs=1.125},
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align=horizontal,     % <-- added
        point meta=rawx,                        % <-- added
        every axis plot/.append style={fill},
        y = 1.2cm,
        xmode=log,log basis x=10
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(168000, 0) (832, 1) (2696, 2) (131162, 3) (31492, 4) (6, 5) (2858, 6) (152196, 7) (698264, 8) (1100, 9)};
        \addplot coordinates {(2487066, 0) (34174, 1) (44184, 2) (409040, 3) (68204, 4) (35200, 5) (35528, 6) (656328, 7) (702332, 8) (38348, 9)};
        \addplot coordinates {(188540, 0) (1268, 1) (1848, 2) (159124, 3) (32788, 4) (836, 5) (2888, 6) (146236, 7) (499024, 8) (2696, 9)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: That works. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.